# Handle different content in XAML binding

Tags: .net, wpf, typescript, xaml, binding

I have a binding in XAML to Validation.Errors.
Sometimes it seems this is a single string and sometimes it is a list of strings.

The following code works fine if it is a single string.
For a list of strings I just get the "System.Generic.List" as an item in the item control.

If I change DisplayMemberPath to be "ErrorContent[0]", it successfully shows the first string if it is a list, but if it happens to be a single string I of course just get the first character.

Question. How can I make it handle both cases (single string type and list type) in XAML?

```
 <ItemsControl     
     x:Name="ErrorDisplay"                                      
     ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Validation.Errors}"   
     DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent"
     Foreground="Red" 
     FontSize="12">
 </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Can Validation.Errors be re-implemented to return a predictable type? If not, you'll likely need a type converter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/type-converters-for-xaml-overview

Comment: Thanks I looked into a converter, but it was easier to use a DataTemplate Selector as Alex.Wei recommended below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define two `DataTemplate`'s for both `String` and `List`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="singleObject">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="collection">
    <Listbox ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then implements a `DataTemplateSelector` class and declare it as resource.

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate
        SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null)
        {
            var ie = item as IEnumerable;
            if (ie == null)
                return
                    element.FindResource("singleObject") as DataTemplate;
            else
                return
                    element.FindResource("collection") as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

<right namespace prefix:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myDataTemplateSelector"/>
```

Finally, set your `DataTemplateSelector` to your `ItemsControl`.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ErrorDisplay" FontSize="12"
              ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Validation.Errors}"   
              DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent" Foreground="Red"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked great. The type of Validation.Errors was of ValidationError and not String / List<Strings> but it was a no brainer to change your answer to work for that instead.

The items control did not accept an ItemTemplateSelector and using a DisplayMemberPath at the same time. I just removed the DisplaymemberPath from ItemsControl and let the DataTemplates bind to ErrorContent instead.

In my case I realized the Validation.Errors type was ValidationError so I had to change the selector class to look at the item's ErrorContent property instead.