# How can you implement the transfer of different data in one layout using ItemControls?

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

I have one page that I go to using MVVM, but I don't know how to pass different values ​​depending on which button I clicked. Those. I have 3 product categories - Pens, Adhesives, Stationery. When I try to go to the glue category, pens are displayed for me.

XAML Code:

```
 <materialDesign:Card Grid.Column="0" materialDesign:ElevationAssist.Elevation="Dp3" Margin="50 0 0 0">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="F:\C#\Stationery\Stationery\IMG\Pen.png" Width="50"/>
                <Button Content="Пишущие принадлежности" 
                        FontSize="18"
                        FontWeight="700"
                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedButton}" 
                        BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Black" 
                        Command="{Binding NavigationToCatalogListCommand}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
                <ItemsControl  Name="icPanList">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="{Binding Cat_Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedButton}" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="#444444"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
```

.cs Code:

```
 public partial class CatalogView : UserControl
{
    public CatalogView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<CatModel> items = new List<CatModel>();
        DB db = new DB();
        db.openConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ID, Title FROM Category WHERE Cat_Name = 'Handles_CN' OR Cat_Name = 'Pencils_CN' OR Cat_Name = ' Colour_pencils_CN' OR Cat_Name = 'Brushes_CN'", db.GetConnection());
        using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                items.Add(new CatModel() {ID = rd.GetInt32(0), Cat_Name = rd.GetString(1)});
            }
        }
        icPanList.ItemsSource = items;
    }
    
    public class CatModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Cat_Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I will also provide you with the code and layout of the page where the products themselves are displayed.

Page with products from the category:

```
<StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl Name="icGoodsList">
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <materialDesign:Card Margin="20 10 20 10">
                       <DockPanel>
                           <Image Source="F:\C#\Stationery\Stationery\IMG\Pen.png" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0 0 50 0"/>
                           <StackPanel
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           >
                               <DockPanel>
                                   <TextBlock 
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       FontWeight="600"
                                       Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                                   <StackPanel Margin="20 10 0 0">
                                       <TextBlock
                                           Text="В наличии"
                                           Foreground="Chartreuse"
                                       />
                                       <TextBlock
                                           Text="{Binding Count}"
                                       />
                                   </StackPanel>
                               </DockPanel>
              
                               <TextBlock
                                   FontSize="18"
                                   FontWeight="400"
                                   MaxWidth="250"
                                   MaxHeight="50"
                                   Margin="0 0 200 0"
                                   Text="{Binding Desc}"
                               />
                           </StackPanel>
                           <TextBlock
                               Foreground="#444444"
                               Margin="50 0 0 0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               FontSize="26"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Text="{Binding Cost}"
                           />
                       </DockPanel>
                   </materialDesign:Card>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

cs Code:

```
 InitializeComponent();
    List<GoodsModel> items = new List<GoodsModel>();
    DB db = new DB();
    db.openConnection();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ID, Title, Description, Count, Cost FROM Goods WHERE Cat = 1 OR Cat = 2 OR Cat = 3 OR Cat = 4", db.GetConnection());
    using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            items.Add(new GoodsModel() {ID = rd.GetInt32(0), Title = rd.GetString(1), Desc = rd.GetString(2), Count = rd.GetInt32(3), Cost = rd.GetInt32(4)});
        }
    }
    icGoodsList.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: You need to prepare 3 `DataTemplate` for 3 sets of data, a implementation of `DataTemplateSelector` and set the an instance of your `DataTemplateSelector` to `ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector`. See my answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332117/handle-different-content-in-xaml-binding/54341511#54341511).

Comment: You don't need a DataTemplateSelector! Just define 3 data types, one for each category. Then define a DataTemplate for each type (make sure to set the DataTemplate.DataType property). Add the templates to a ResourceDictionary within the scope of the ItemsControl. WPF will automatically pick the proper DataTemplate based on the current item for you. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Note that in an MVVM application database handling belongs into the Model. The View is not concerned with data except presenting it (usually via DataTemplates). Also using a ListView will improve the performance (it implements UI virtualization) and allows for scrolling by default. There is no MVVM code in your example. It's just common code: your view does everything.